# Probability: Bayer's theorem

Tags: statistics

Can anyone let me know if I am following the correct format/procedures in solving this problem and have came up with the correct answer?

P(L1)= .60

P(L2)= .40

10% of the calculator produced on line 1 is defective 
P(D|L1)=.10

20% of the calculator produced on line 2 is defective 
P(D|L2)=.20

What is the probability that the defective calculator comes 
from Line 1 ?

P(L1|D) = P(L1)P(D|L1) / [ P(L1)P(D|L1) + P(L2)P(D|L2)]

= (.60)(.10) /[(.60)(.10)+ (.40)(.20)]

=.4286

What is the probability that the defective calculator comes 
from Line 2 ?

P(L2|D) = P(L2)P(D|L2) / [ P(L1)P(D|L1) + P(L2)P(D|L2)]

= (.40)(.20) /[(.60)(.10)+ (.40)(.20)]

=.5714

Comment: You surely mean "Bayes's" theorem

Comment: Peter: That is correct, it is Bayes's theorem that I am working on. Can you let me know if my work is correct?

Comment: The downvotes are hard to understand. The OP gives a solution and wants to know whether it is right. So, I do not see any reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have calculated everything correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. It is greatly appreciated.